# How can I achieve "onContinuousPress" like behaviour?

Tags: button, flutter, gesture

Let's say that I have this button somewhere in my Flutter app:

```
FloatingActionButton(
 backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
 child: Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
 onPressed: _someAction,
);
```

I want that `_someAction()` will be executed as long as my finger is tapping on the button (i.e. if I tap continuously for T seconds `_someAction()` 
should be execute **N times**,

where `N=(int)(60/T + 1))`

I looked into [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)
but couldn't find what I need there.
I need this for example in order to increase/decrease some `int` value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int _value = 0;
Timer _timer;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return GestureDetector(
    onTapDown: (details) => _startTimer(true),
    onTapUp: (details) => _startTimer(false),
    child: FlutterLogo(size: 200),
  );
}

void _startTimer(bool start) {
  if (!start) {
    _timer.cancel();
    return;
  }
  // you can adjust the timings here
  _timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(milliseconds: 1), (_) => _myMethod());
}

// this method will be getting called as long as you hold
void _myMethod() => print("value = ${++_value}");
```

Comment: Thanks, it did work. i just made a minor change so it will be more clear,  [see here](https://repl.it/repls/SalmonAdventurousStrategies) also, I opened a feature request on flutter project. [feature](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33110)

Comment: @Shai Glad to hear it work but seems like you accepted different answer, can you recheck it?

Comment: can't I accept both of your answers? They're both good solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Use `onTapDown` and `onTapUp` from `GestureDetector` and `Timer` to achieve your goal.

**GestureDetector**

```
onTapDown: (_) => setState(() {
    _timerStart = true;
    _restartTimer();
}),
onTapUp: (_) => setState(() => _timerStart = false),
```

**Some Action**

```
void _restartTimer() {
  _timer?.cancel();
  _timer = Timer(Duration(milliseconds: 100), () {
    // _someAction()
    if (_timerStart) {
        _restartTimer();
    }
  });
}
```